# How to do nested query filtering in graph

Tags: graphql, dgraph

I have some movie data in my Dgraph

```json
[
    {
        name: movie1
        release: 2016
        mainActor: {
            uid: 0x12
            name: actor1
            birth: 1990
        }
    },
    {
        name: movie2
        release: 2017
        mainActor: {
            uid: 0x15
            name: actor2
            birth: 1991
        }
    },
    {
        name: movie3
        release: 2018
        mainActor: {
            uid: 0x12
            name: actor1
            birth: 1990
        }
    }
]
```

I want to get all movies that have mainActor set as actor1. This is the query I have currently:

```json
{
    movies(func: type(Movie)) {
        name
        release
        mainActor @filter(uid(0x12)) {
            name
            birth
        }
    }
}
```

Expected output:

```json
[
    {
        name: movie1
        release: 2016
        mainActor: {
            uid: 0x12
            name: actor1
            birth: 1990
        }
    },
    {
        name: movie3
        release: 2018
        mainActor: {
            uid: 0x12
            name: actor1
            birth: 1990
        }
    }
]
```

However, the actual output is a bit weird and doesn't do what I want it to.

```json
[
    {
        name: movie1
        release: 2016
        mainActor: {
            uid: 0x12
            name: actor1
            birth: 1990
        }
    },
    {
        name: movie2
        release: 2017
    },
    {
        name: movie3
        release: 2018
        mainActor: {
            uid: 0x12
            name: actor1
            birth: 1990
        }
    }
]
```

What am I doing wrong here? I want to filter out the main result based on the nested object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, the `@cascade(paramName)` can be used to filter out results that don't have a specific property. In my case, since I don't have a `mainActor` after filtering them out by uid, I could use `@cascade(mainActor)` to remove all `movies` that don't have a `mainActor` predicate.

```
{
    movies(func: type(Movie)) 
    @cascade(mainActor)
    {
        name
        release
        mainActor @filter(uid(0x12)) {
            name
            birth
        }
    }
}
```